# Linear Independence of a Subset of $M_{2\times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine if the following subset of $M_{2\times 2}$ is linearly independent:
$$U = \left\lbrace\begin {bmatrix} 1&1 \\\\ 0&1 \ \end{bmatrix}, \begin {bmatrix} 1&0 \\\\ 1&1 \ \end{bmatrix}, \begin {bmatrix} 1&1 \\\\ 1&1 \ \end{bmatrix} \right\rbrace$$

I am approaching the problem with:
 $$ c_1 \begin {bmatrix} 1&1 \\\\ 0&1 \ \end{bmatrix} + c_2 \begin {bmatrix} 1&0 \\\\ 1&1 \ \end{bmatrix} + c_3 \begin {bmatrix} 1&1 \\\\ 1&1 \ \end{bmatrix} = 0$$
from the above I get:
$$c_1+c_2+c_3=0 \\ c_1 + c_3=0 \\ c_2+c_3=0 \\ c_1+c_2+c_3=0$$
but when I solve it, I end up with an inconsistent system. Doesn't this mean the system is neither LI or LD? Or did I mess up somewhere.

Comment: You messed up somewhere. If the right side is zero, then the system is necessarily consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting the 2nd equation into the 1st gives $c_2=0$. Substituting into the 3rd equation gives $c_3=0$, and then the 1st equation gives $c_1=0$.  Therefore the vectors are linearly independent.